# C# Discord Bot - get Userinput on a command parameter

Tags: c#, bots, discord

I want to teach my DiscordBot how to deal with a Input after writing the command.

I create the Command this way:

```
private void CreateCommand(string commandName, string parameterName, ParameterType parameterType , string commandValue) // Register this command by the name and the answer value
        {
            commands.CreateCommand(commandName).Parameter(parameterName, parameterType).Do(async (e) =>
            {
                await e.Channel.SendMessage(commandValue); // Bots answer
            });
        }
```

I use this method to short my Code of the next method:

```
private void Add(string commandName, string commandValue, string commandDescription) // Add a simple command to the List
        {
            singleCommandList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(commandName, commandValue, commandDescription));
        }

        private void Add(string commandName, string parameterName, ParameterType parameterType, string commandValue, string commandDescription) // Add commands with Parameters to the List
        {
            parameterCommandList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, ParameterType, string, string>(commandName, parameterName, parameterType, commandValue, commandDescription));
        }
```

And this is the method filling my CommandList

```
 private void FillCommandList() // Add all the commands to the List
        {
            Add("test", "success", "test"); // simple Command
            Add("search", "onlineSearch", ParameterType.Multiple, Search("text to look for"), "Google it");
        }
```

My Problem is that I do not know, how to fill the Parameter of the method `Search()`. What would I have to pass in there? Something with `e.User` ..?

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own Discord.Net bot using this unofficial Discord C# Wrapper:

[An unofficial .NET API Wrapper for the Discord client](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/tree/dev)
[Their Discord Server](https://discord.gg/0SBTUU1wZTVjAMPx)

The examples given in the documentation are not always up to date, since they made a huge and code breaking rewrite of their API but it is really well done using the async patterns.
That should give you more examples and ideas on how to continue with your idea.

Make sure using the 1.0 version - the dev branch. (as of now)

Everything else is described on their Github. If you still need answers join their discord. They are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.GetArg("parameterName")` to get the parameter named "parameterName". This works if the `ParameterType` is `Optional` or `Required`.

If your `ParameterType` is `Multiple`, try:

```
    string search = string.Join(" ", e.Args)
```

to get the entire "onlineSearch" parameter.

Comment: Actually, the entire API has changed.